How to get Disallowed Comment Keys programmatically from WordPress admin > Settings > Discussion?
In wp-admin, the admin can set a list of terms in Settings > Discussion that can be used to block spam comments.
This list is also used by other plugins, such as Contact Form 7, to help prevent contact form spam.
I'd like to know how to access this Disallowed Comment Keys list programmatically so I can utilise it in my own plugin?

Re the close votes, how could this question be more focused?!

$disallowed_comment_keys_list = get_option( 'disallowed_keys' );
$disallowed_comment_keys_array = explode( "\n", $disallowed_comment_keys_list );


// Retrieve the disallowed comment keys from the database
$disallowed_keys = get_option('disallowed_keys');
// Check if the option exists and is not empty
if (!empty($disallowed_keys) && is_array($disallowed_keys)) {
// Use the disallowed keys in your plugin logic

foreach ($disallowed_keys as $key) {

    // Your logic here

    echo $key . "<br>";

}

}
else
{
// Handle the case when the option is empty or doesn't exist
echo "No disallowed comment keys found.";
}
You can place this code snippet in your plugin file where you need to access the disallowed comment keys.

In my experience, we cannot use default discussion setting on wordpress. I just want to suggest to use this plugin anyway. Thanks.
https://wordpress.org/plugins/turn-off-comments/
